# Dynamic properties evaluation in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I retrieve property values in runtime and compute them in the context of angular?

For example, I have component:

```
@Component({          
    selector: 'my-app',  
    template: '<h1>{{name}}</h1>'  
})       
export class AppComponent {  
    name: string = "Angular 6"
    @Input() x: Number = 2
    @Input() y: Number = 3
}
```

And I have markup:

```
<my-app dynamic1="{{x+y}}" dynamic2="{{x*y}}"></my-app>
```

In method of the component I need to retrieve list of "dynamic" attributes (dynamic1 and dynamic2) and its values, computed in Angular context. In other words, I need to get object

```
{
  dynamic1: 5,
  dynamic2: 6
}
```

How can I achieve this?

For a better understanding of the problem here is solution for AngularJS:
https://jsfiddle.net/qp9ngdLu/16/

Comment: Will you use those values outside of angular?

Comment: dynamic1 and dynamic2 are @input properties, use property binding for this i.e:
`[dynamic1]="x+y"`

Comment: @AsadShah :The goal is not to describe these properties in the component code, but to get them at runtime

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner No

Comment: @Interloper who is going to set those attributes dynamically? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Bunyamin Coskuner: I will be set those attributes in templates of parent components

Comment: @Interloper let me see if I get it right. You use your custom component (the one with X, Y) within your other components which will decide on some context and calculate dynamic1, 2, 3 etc. Also, they will use those dynamic values, not that custom component right?

Comment: @Bunyamin Coskuner: You are almost right. But the values of dynamic1, 2, 3 etc. I want to get and use in my component (which has X, Y).

Comment: I add to question solution for AngularJS for demosntration of problem.

Comment: Okay, now I got it. But, it feels like this could be solved in another way. If, your component (the one with X, Y, let's call it `xy-comp`)  will use those dynamic values, then `xy-comp` needs to know what variables it has.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner: No need to know what variables. For example I just want to create JSON with this variables and post to my backend. And I do not care about key names

Comment: @Interloper okay, I posted an answer based on our conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `@Input` bindings to evaluate `dynamic1/dynamic2` variables.

You can have your component.ts as below:-

```
@Input() dynamic1: string;
@Input() dynamic2: string;
```

and your HTML component can be called as:-

```
<hello name="{{ name }}" [dynamic1]="x+y" [dynamic2]="x*y"></hello>
```

Please take a look at the following code:-

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfgyhr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Names "dynamic1" and "dynamic2" are not known in advance. I need to discover them in runtime.

Comment: Where do you think the `x` and `y` values are coming from? It must be coming from some component, I believe. Hence, you can have them as `@Input` values.

Comment: You are right, x and y have Input decorator both. But dynamic1 and dynamic2 - do not.

Comment: If `x` and `y` have `@Input` decorator. Where are they defined? It must be somewhere in some component. When you are using them to assign `dynamic` attributes, that component is the child component generally. Hence, it is safe to use it as coded above. If you still are not clear on what you want to get, kindly create a stackblitz and write a detailed explanation about your expectations.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trq5zz
I want to get console output as below:
x=2
y=3
dynamic1=5
dynamic2=6

Comment: If I am able to understand you better this time, please look into this library https://github.com/vinayk406/angular-expression-parser and could just send the expression `dynamic1='x+y'` and user sth like `$eval` to calculate `dynamic1` inside the component itself. It is just a hint and not a solution itself.

Comment: Thank's. But this library give a half of solution, another half is how to get list of dynamic attributes.

Comment: To get a list of attributes, you may use `elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('someattribute')` to get all dynamic attributes and then use that library to evaluate expressions.

Comment: I got the closest solution to the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajjqjc
In this solution no need to use a third-party library.

Comment: Glad, you got a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very exhaustive : I had to read your comments on an answer to get what yuou wanted.

If I understood correctly, you need to get the values given dynamically to your component.

Although it can be problematic because of minification, here is how you can do it.

```
<app-component [dynamic]="obj"></app-component>
```

Where

```
obj = {
  dynamicPropertyOne: "One",
  dynamicPropertyTwo: "Two",
};
```

In your child component :

```
@Input() dynamic: { [key: string]: string };
```

You will have access to all of the dynamic properties you pass into the component.

Comment: It is not solution of my problem because I'll have to list the names of all properties in the component code. I want to avoid this.

Comment: No you won't. you just give the object as an input, and you don't touch the keys.

Comment: This is another task. I do not want to have a root object for storing values. I want to access the top-level properties with any names.

Comment: Inputs have to be named. If you can't name them, this is the solution.

Comment: basically, this is what `SimpleChanges` wrapper is in `ngOnChanges`. i think he has some design flaw. maybe we can get more clarification of what the actual intention is.

Comment: No, it isn't. `SimpleChanges` report on properties it knows, which are the defined inputs. You can think what you want, but this isn't a website to share your opinion, this is a website to post questions about your coding issues. I gave you the solution : if you're not happy with it, consider opening a github issue.

Comment: sorry, but you didn't give me anything (i didn't ask the question) and please keep your nervousness for yourself. this is the comment section purpose of which is commenting other peoples answers.

Comment: My bad on this one, I'm author-agnostic (I answer without reading who posted comments/questions/answers). and I'm not nervous, I'm very calm : I explain the procedure one has to follow if he wants to resolve an issue, and if he wants to ask for an evolution of an existing framework. And I know what the comment section is, that's why I'm answering you and explaining that what you said isn't true.

Comment: i haven't seen any explanation why anything i said was untrue. the way he asked question by passing explicitly `dynamic1` and `dynamic2` and then building object with those 2 properties > there is no important difference between `SimpleChanges` and your solution. Of course, i am aware of your solution working for cases behind known/explicitly passed property names since one can extend wrapper object without declarations. That's why i said his question is unclear.

Comment: Okay, I understood it this way : `basically, this is what SimpleChanges wrapper is in ngOnChanges` = `ngOnChanges gets the inputs dynamically so you should be able to do it too`. So the difference with my solution and `ngOnChanges` is that `ngOnChanges` need inputs to be named, whereas my solution forces you to only name one, that will contain dynamic keys as changes. `SimpleChanges` does not allow that.

Comment: i don't know why you got caught up on my comment since your solution is good. my point was that his question was asked in a bad way because he says he wants  to avoid explicit property naming but then explicitly names them. in that scenario, effect is the same. but of course that your passing only one wrapper object is the solution. that's exactly why i said in the same line: " i think he has some design flaw. maybe we can get more clarification of what the actual intention is."

Comment: @deezg: I added to question solution for AngularJS. In this you can see that explicit property naming is avoiding. I understand that this problem is associated with bad design, but I am interested in with the principle possibility of solving the problem on Angular.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I understood what you need. This question felt like [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at the beginning and it turned out I was right.

As you said in your last comment, you will just create a custom JSON and post it to your backend. For this, you don't need to create a component. You can just create a common service and inject it everywhere you need. It is because, you set `X` and `Y`, how to calculate those and all of the dynamic variables. You might as well just call a service within your components. The component you try to create does not really do anything.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBackendService() {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    post<T>(url, body) {
        return this.httpClient.post<T>(url, body, { observe: 'body' });
    }
}
```

One of your business component

```
@Component({
    select: 'my-business-comp',
    template: ....
})
export class MyBusinessComponent {

    x = 2;
    y = 3;

    constructor(private customBackendService: CustomBackendService) {}

    // you should call this method somehow
    callBackend() {
        const input = {
             dynamic1: this.x + this.y,
             dynamic2: this.x * this.y
        };
        this.customBackendService.post('some-url', input).subscribe(result => {
             console.log(result);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not solution of my problem. The meaning of it is to extract the properties of the markup component. Look at the solution on AngularJS (link in question).

Comment: I checked that link out. You set `x=2` and `y=3` meaning `my-business-comp` has those values within itself. You don't need to extract properties from anywhere.

Comment: Why not? In example I extract expressions in runtime and evaluate it. In Angular there is no simple way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you do that but do you really need to? As I shown in my example, you can simply calculate everything you need within your components. You don't need to pass variable names (`dynamic1`, `dynamic2`) and their expressions (`x + y`,  `x * y`). Because, your common component does not really do anything. It just passes everything to your backend. A service can do that as well.

Comment: Service cannot read values form markup because it hasn't any markup representation.

Comment: Service is not going to read anything from markup, your components will send those values as input

Comment: Exactly. And you can come up with a case where you want to get values dynamically from the markup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177482/discussion-between-bunyamin-coskuner-and-interloper).

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to get them directly, as far as i know.

What you can do is utilize `ngOnChanges` (which will get called for all of your `@Input` decorated properties) and build your custom object within it.

Comment: I do not have @Input decorators, because I do not know the names of properties in advance

Comment: did you downvote? if so, please try to understand what i wrote. you don't need to know `@Input` decorated properties; `ngOnChanges` solves that. that's the whole point.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But your solution does not suit me, because it involves enumerating all the properties in the component code

Comment: hm...i must admit i don't understand. could you maybe explain a bit what are you actually trying to accomplish? what usecase?

Comment: I'm trying to explain. I want to get all the expressions "name = value" passed to the markup of my component and compute expressions in the angular context, that is, these expressions can contain angular expressions of the form "{{x + y}}"

Comment: that's not an usecase explanation. that's proposing solution which, from what we've seen so far, is probably wrong. you already got a few different solutions for what you asked and you still think its not solved. so, please explain outside of angular language. what usecase are you solving?

Comment: My usecase is discovering of passing properties in a runtime. And property names are not known at the time of writing the component code.

Comment: whatever you pass to your component as property, it must be decorated with `@Input` within component code. And if you don't want to list&decorate each individual property then wrapper object is what you must do, like @trichetriche posted in his answer.